# How to insert data from numbers of rows read from csv into a rdf file using jena in Java?

Tags: java, loops, csv, rdf, jena

```
try {

        br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(csvFile));
        final Resource FlightOperations = model.createResource(NS+"FlightOperations");

        int i=0;
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            //  j++;

            String[] flightOperation = line.split(cvsSplitBy);

            model.addLiteral (FlightOperations, rowID, i);
            model.addLiteral (FlightOperations, DataExtractDate, ResourceFactory.createTypedLiteral(flightOperation[0], XSDDatatype.XSDdate));
            model.addLiteral (FlightOperations, ReportPeriod, ResourceFactory.createTypedLiteral(flightOperation[1], XSDDatatype.XSDdate));
            model.addLiteral (FlightOperations, FlightType, ResourceFactory.createTypedLiteral(flightOperation[2], XSDDatatype.XSDstring));
            model.addLiteral (FlightOperations, arrival_departure, ResourceFactory.createTypedLiteral(flightOperation[3], XSDDatatype.XSDstring));
            model.addLiteral (FlightOperations, domestic_international, ResourceFactory.createTypedLiteral(flightOperation[4], XSDDatatype.XSDstring));
            model.addLiteral (FlightOperations, flightOpsCount, ResourceFactory.createTypedLiteral(flightOperation[5], XSDDatatype.XSDint));

            i++;
        }
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

I am not able to print the the values in the correct order that are in the ccsv file. I want to build rdf with 1369 rows of csv.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wkFkz.png)

Answer (score 0):

An RDF graph does not preserve order.

If you are simply printing the RDF, it does not matter.

If you are querying the RDF, sort by the recorded row number `rowID`.